# when i run the flutter project it's happing

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, visual-studio-code

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Unable to get mutable Windows environment variable map
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Can you add the log entirely ?

Comment: Can you add the commands you are running?